# How can I create carousel post with Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to create carousel post in Facebook Graph API? If I'm trying to post to feed with child_attachments the result is an error((#10) Application does not have permission for this action), if I'm trying in two steps(creating a post and updating with child_attachments) the result is success: true, but nothing is happening, and same goes for creating a post on FB, then getting the data on graph api and posting back with different data.

Comment: Please can you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Is that even possible for normal posts? I think that might be a feature only available for ads - https://www.facebook.com/business/ads/carousel-ad-format